# Обратимость функций в алгоритме SHA-256

Tags: криптография, sha256

Обратимы ли функции BSIG0,BSIG1,SSIG0(x),SSIG0(x) в алгоритме SHA-256?

```
BSIG0(x) = ROTR^2(x) XOR ROTR^13(x) XOR ROTR^22(x)
BSIG1(x) = ROTR^6(x) XOR ROTR^11(x) XOR ROTR^25(x)
SSIG0(x) = ROTR^7(x) XOR ROTR^18(x) XOR SHR^3(x)
SSIG1(x) = ROTR^17(x) XOR ROTR^19(x) XOR SHR^10(x)
```

То есть, например:

Для функции `y=BSIG0(x)`, возможно ли найти такую функцию F, чтобы выполнялось условие:

```
x=F(BSIG0(x))
```

Comment: О какой именно функции идет речь - не ясно. К тому же есть подозрение что автор вопроса не захотел ознакомиться со статьями, посвященными SHA256. Поэтому под закрытие.

Comment: Функции S0, S1, E0, E1.

Comment: К тому же, ни один документ не говорит о том, обратимы ли они или нет. Или у Вас есть другая документация?

Comment: Ответ в понимании аббревиатуры SHA

Comment: SHA-2 (англ. Secure Hash Algorithm Version 2 — безопасный алгоритм хеширования, версия 2). А где в нем про обратимость этих функций?

Comment: А в каком описании есть эти функции? Например в псевдокоде в вики никаких функций нет

Comment: В RFC4634 и RFC6234 (можно считать официальным описанием алгоритма) никаких функций с такими названиями не упоминается.

Comment: Названия функций я брал из Википедии. В RFC они называются по другому. Вопрос я исправил. Теперь так - как в RFC.

Comment: Разумеется они НЕ обратимы.

Comment: Это интуитивно понятно, но как это доказать?

Comment: I have inverses for BSIG0(x) and BSIG1(x).